# Persist javascript variables across pages?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way we can persist javascript variables across various pages? Suppose in Page A I am setting `window.someVar = 5`. Then I move to Page B, via clicking a hyperlink in A, and do something like `alert(window.someVar)` -- I should get a message box displaying 5. Is there a technique to persist `someVar` as such...?

Comment: Take a look a this answer: **[How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17309679/2247494)**

Comment: Also you can find a complete answer here: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070207/2247494**

Comment: The accepted answer definitely should be changed. Currently the Storage API is the standard for persisting values. The `window.name` approach is obsolete.

Comment: Yes there are, these are called [javascript cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You could use the window’s name `window.name` to store the information. This is known as [JavaScript session](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html). But it only works as long as the same window/tab is used.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a permanent link to a session using this technique, so that the session data could be stored in the page's URL?

Comment: @AndersonGreen The storage is bound to the actual window/tab. If the window/tab is closed, the data is lost. If you’re looking for a more persistent solution, have a look at [CMS’ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1981736/53114). Techniques like [Web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) have a different scope.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to save and load the session data from the page's URL, like this: `myPage.html#sessionDataGoesHere`.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, that would be possible. The URI’s fragment is accessible via `location.hash`.

Comment: @Gumbo I found out that it's possible to store a JavaScript object in a page's URL. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15399819/975097

Comment: It doesn't work with me. The browser issues `sessvars.newObj` is undefined

Comment: I feel like when I look for my keys and then I realize I got them in my hand. Thank you for this trick!

Comment: It doesn't work with me either. Even I see this page http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessvarsTestPage1.html working fine and with same js file as I'm using. Don't know why.

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy I glanced at this and when you said "Superb Gumbo" I was thinking maybe "Gumbo" was a coder's word for a hack of a particularly specific kind... in fact I think every hack specifically about JS should henceforth be called a "Gumbo" in honour of Gumbo's answer...

Comment: There's some discussion that window.name will be depreciated in Firefox at least due to the security risk that any website can read the window.name set by any other website. Is there a more secure way I wonder?

Comment: Some examples using *url* and *web storage*: **[How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17309679/2247494)** and a complete answer here: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070207/2247494**

Answer (score 58):

For completeness, also look into the local storage capabilities & sessionStorage of HTML5. These are supported in the latest versions of all modern browsers, and are much easier to use and less fiddly than cookies.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20091222/

https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/. (second edition)

Here are some sample code for setting and getting the values using sessionStorage and localStorage :

```
 // HTML5 session Storage
 sessionStorage.setItem("variableName","test");
 sessionStorage.getItem("variableName");


//HTML5 local storage 
localStorage.setItem("variableName","Text");
// Receiving the data:
localStorage.getItem("variableName");
```

Comment: Ref for implementation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionStorage

Comment: Hmm [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) Claims IE8 is ok for sessionStorage, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionStorage) claims that IE11 is required.

Answer (score 28):

I would recommend you to give a look to this library:

- [PersistJS](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js)

I really like it, it supports a variety of storage backends (from cookies to HTML5 storage, Gears, Flash, and more...), its usage is really *transparent*, you don't have to know or care which backend is used the library will choose the right storage backend depending on the browser capabilities.

Comment: can it store large objects aswell? For Example window objects

Comment: Can it store objects having circular / cyclic reference? Like popup `window` object? Or, native objects like HTML5 File API File object?

Comment: @MohsinSheikhKhalid http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557 this link is outdated for migrated... please can update the link

Comment: The link is outdated.. because it is migrating.. you can update it? @CMS

Answer (score 14):

Yes, using [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). But be careful, don't put too much in them (I think there is a limit at 4kb). But a few variables are ok.

If you need to store considerably more than that, check out @Annie's great tips in the other answer. For small time data storage, I would say Cookies are the easiest thing.

Note that cookies are stored client side.

Comment: Other downside of cookies is that they are sent along with every HTTP request within the domain which were created, even with *static* content like images...

Answer (score 9):

You can persist values using HTML5 storage, Flash Storage, or Gears. The [dojo storage](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/node/115) library provides a nice wrapper for this.

Comment: updated link - https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store.html

Answer (score 7):

I recommend web storage. Example:

`// Storing the data:
localStorage.setItem("variableName","Text");
// Receiving the data:
localStorage.getItem("variableName");`

Just replace `variable` with your variable name and `text` with what you want to store. According to W3Schools, it's better than cookies.

Comment: This works for a single domain, not across multiple domains. Not much useful in my case.

Comment: @MasudRahman You can also persist variables across domains using [using `postMessage()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957989/975097) with an embedded iframe.