# how to exchange variables between two HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, query-string, href

I have two HTML pages, `example1.html` and `example2.html`.

How do I pass variables from `example1.html` to `example2.html` using the query string, and retrieve that variable in `example2.html` without using any serverside code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass javascript object from one page to other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709289/how-to-pass-javascript-object-from-one-page-to-other)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Variable usage on page reload](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29986657/2247494)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17309199/2247494)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing javascript variables between pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11581543/2247494)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In example1.html:

```
<a href='example2.html?myVar1=42'>a link</a>
<a href='example2.html?myVar1=43'>another link</a>
```

or generate the links with Javascript as desired.  Just make sure the ?varName=value gets onto the end of example2.html somehow.

Then, in example2.html, you use Javascript to parse the query string that example2 came with.

To do this, you could try Querystring.

```
// Adapted from examples on the Querystring homepage.
var qs = new Querystring();
var v1 = qs.get("myVar1");
```

Alternatively, parent.document.URL contains the complete URI for the page you're on.  You could extract that:

```
parent.document.URL.substring(parent.document.URL.indexOf('?'), parent.document.URL.length);
```

and parse it manually to pull the variables you encoded into the URI.

EDIT: Forgot the 'new' part of 'new Querystring()'.  Oops...

Comment: Thanks for the reply i tried the second method what you suggested its working fine , i have writtten like var a=parent.document.URL.substring(parent.document.URL.indexOf('myVar1='), parent.document.URL.length);
alert(a);

Comment: But the problem is i have to store only 42 into variable a ,when i write alert(a); it displays myVar1=42 ,but how will i display only 42

Comment: From a quick glance (I'm a beginner trying to figure this out also), the example code  has the index of 0 is just before the '?'. save the index it finds to a variable. Set a string variable to the name of the variable so you can measure the length property. Then when calling the value of your case it would be var myString = "?myVar1="; then alert(a + myString.Length); to shift to the right the number of characters needed.

Answer (score 7):

HTML / HTTP is stateless, this means that, what you did / saw on the previous page, is completely disconnected with the current page.Question is How to pass variable between two pages in front end. (As HTTP is stateless, every time you load the page it will use the initial values of whatever you set in JavaScript. You can't set a global variable in JS and simply make that value stay after loading the page again.

There are a couple of ways you could store the value in another place so that you can initialize it on load using JavaScript)

1) - Simple using Front End Storages, which equips any Browser (Cookie, Session Storage, Local Storage - which for security reasons available throughout one domain -> it means you can save data on this storage only for one domain, another domain can't access this data ) and put value in one page and get value in others.
Considering that:

> Cookie saves data until what time you have determined,
>
> Session Storage saves data until the browser default tab closed.
>
> Local Storage saves data until Browser completely closed and shares data between tabs (pages)  It stores data with no expiration date, and gets cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser Cache / Locally Stored Data - unlike cookie expiry.

2) – Add attributes to the element when it generated via Ajax render function

```
<a href='example2.html?action=getAll&element=product&id=1'>a link</a>
<a href='example2.html?action=getAll&element=product&id=2'>another link</a>
```

-> and after click this element construct “ URL / ? action=getAll & element=product & id=1 “ and in second page which will be gone action you can parse this URL and call appropriate Ajax with appropriate parameters.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of cookies and Querystring to exchange values.