# Passing a variable to a new function (on a new page)

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

On my first page I have two radio buttons, each with a value. When the link is clicked to go to page 2, the following for loop runs and gets the value of the checked button. (That script works, I've tested it):

```
function func1(){
    var info = document.Information;
    for(var i1 = 0;i1 < info.length;i1++){
        if (info.elements[i1].type == "radio" && info.elements[i1].checked) {
        ordertype = info.elements[i1].value;
        alert(ordertype);       
        }
    }
}
```

The variable ordertype is declared outside of the function. On page two I have this function run on a button click:

```
function func2(){
     alert(ordertype);  
}
```

ordertype is now undefined... How can I correctly pass the variable to the new function?

Comment: JavaScript execution context is not shared between pages.

Comment: Cookies? Sessions? Localstorage? Query string?

Comment: Did page one open page two with a `window.open`?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages

Answer (score 0):

If using javascript... you could pass via querystring:

```
function func1() {

        var info = document.Information;

        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < info.length; i1++) {
            if (info.elements[i1].type == "radio" && info.elements[i1].checked) {
                ordertype = info.elements[i1].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        location = 'page.html?value=' + ordertype;
    }
```

Or simply add a submit-button to your form.

And method=post to you form-tag and you will get the value of the selected radiobutton in the querystring without use of the javascript?