# Passing javascript variables between pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)
>   [how to exchange variables between two html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages)

I am working on creating a "quiz" that allows users to answer questions, then passes their answer and current score to the next page for the next question. I used this article and was able to get the user's answer to pass through to the next window:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111/A-Quick-Tutorial-on-JavaScript-Variable-Passing.htm

The issue is that this passes the information through a form. Once I receive the score on the second page, I need to increment the score if the answer was correct. I can't figure out how to pass a javascript variable with an html form.

I feel like this should be a relatively easy fix, I'm just stumped.

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated!
xoxo

Comment: Is there a reason you're using JavaScript? As opposed to something like PHP, I mean.

Comment: Here you can see an example using **localStorage**
**[How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17309679/2247494)**

Comment: Also a complete answer here: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070207/2247494**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two obvious ways to maintain state in the browser without requiring that the server remember it between pages:

1. Cookies
2. [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

The latter is trivial to implement, but is only available in HTML5.

Note that neither is intended to be *secure* - a determined page hacker could set either to whatever value they wish.

Comment: One can also use querystrings and hashtags as well. Then the receiving page will read the url and parse them. Both are visible though and are easily editable.

Comment: A hashtag is a phase marked as "Please search me" on Twitter and is not to be confused with fragment identifiers on URIs (which are [evil when used for Ajaxy things](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)).

Answer (score 3):

You can submit a form using get method `<form method="get"` then use javascript to parse params in url. [Reference](https://www.google.com.kh/search?q=javascript%20html%20params&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) here:

Comment: But this method is not safe, every one can read the source and change things.... You should have server involve in this case

Comment: And with Java Script this is more "ugly" to use than just simply using localStorage

Comment: Yeah, Urgly but compartiple to more browser, older browser that does not support local storage