# Global variable defined outside of javascript file does not work

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a html file:

```
<body>
  <?php 
    $rand1 = rand(0,10);
    $rand2 = rand(0,20);
  ?>

  <span id="client-registration-button">Registration</span>

  <script>var checksum = <?php echo $rand1+$rand2; ?>;</script>
  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

And in main.js is:

```
$('#client-registration-button').click(function() {         
    alert(checksum);    
});
```

But the alert shows no value, just empty alert window. Why is there no value of global variable "checksum" displayed?

Comment: Do you know the var is populated? Have you tested it in the HTML file first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309199/how-to-send-variables-from-one-file-to-another-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes it is, here is an output: <script>var checksum = 22;</script>