# Firebase initialize app lose Current User

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web application using html-js-css and a flask server.
My web app is a multi-pages app which apparently means that I have to Initialize firebase for each page in which i want to use it -.-

The problem is that every time I initialize firebase app, I lose the current user so while in my main page, after log-in, if I write:

```js
const USER = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(USER.uid);
```

I get my user ID, as soon as I move to another page and repeat the above code, I get the error:

```
TypeError: USER is null
```

Is there a way to either:

- avoid Initializing the firebase-app at avery page
- keep the CurrentUser (even storing it **securely** somewhere)

Thank you

**Workaround:**

I got this workaround working before Frank answer which is probably the best way to proceed. Instead I just stored the user id in an encrypted variable accessible to all pages.

Since the main.html page is always loaded, I store/removed the variable in a `onAuthStateChanged` listener there so as soon as the user is logged out, that variable is removed:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        cached_uid = JSON.stringify(user.uid);
        cached_uid = btoa(cached_uid);
        localStorage.setItem('_uid',cached_uid);
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('_uid');
    }
});
```

then on the other pages:

```js
function loadUID(){
        var uid = localStorage.getItem('_uid');
        if (!uid) return false;
        uid = atob(uid);
        uid = JSON.parse(uid);
        return uid
      }
```

I followed this to find this solution:
[How to send variables from one file to another in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309199/how-to-send-variables-from-one-file-to-another-in-javascript/17309679#17309679)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to initialize the Firebase app on each page, but that is supposed to be a fairly cheap operation.

To pick up the user on the new page, Firebase runs a check against the server to ensure the user token is still valid. Since this code calls a server, its result likely isn't available yet when your `firebase.auth().currentUser` runs.

To solve this, run the code that requires a user in a so-called auth state change listener:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: Thank you Frank, I actually found a workaround which was to store the UID in an encrypted variable. see my question edit.

Comment: Great to hear! Two things: 1) there's no need to encrypt the UID, as it's not a secret. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37221760, 2) please post your workaround as an answer, instead of in the question.Posting self-answers is acceptable and even encouraged on Stack Overflow.