# Link back to a certain point of a Javascript controlled page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this template from codyhouse: https://codyhouse.co/gem/pointy-slider/

I'm using the slider to link to other external pages - the problem I have is when I send the user back to the template it reverts to the first slider.

I've tried using the # id a link to go back to a certain point of the template but the .hidden .visible attribute in the JS stopping this technique from working.

Is there a solution to link back to a certain slide?

Comment: What have you done so far? Could you provide us a JSFiddle?

Comment: So, if I understand well, you want that e.g. when the user clicks on slide 8, the web site goes to detail page.
Then, when it goes back or clicks on "Back to Projects", the carousel should begin from slide 8, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is used for pagination (numbers at the bottom):

```
sliderPagination.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected = $(this),
    index = selected.index();
    updateSlider(index, sliderPagination, slides);
});
```

This means you can use this code by calling `updateSlider` with the parameters you need.

I'd suggest altering the source to store `index, sliderPagination, slides` in a cookie and on navigating to the page again first checking if there is no cookie in session

Comment: if you provide a fiddle, I will provide an example

Comment: @KitDebuse it doesn't have multiple pages

Comment: @KitDebuse https://jsfiddle.net/Lugy30nz/5/ Shows where I added a line to go back to the page on index 3 (4th page / 0-based) You can store this in a cookie like this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @KitDebuse Could you ask it more clearly or even better yet: in a new question (please link it here then, because otherwise I don't notice)

Comment: @KitDebuse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581543/passing-javascript-variables-between-pages
as I said: cookies (or local storage). If the variable is not set, let it default to the first page!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) index (*i.e.* 0, 1, ..., N - 1) in a [`sessionStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) variable (*e.g.* `carouselIndex`) when you click on it.

Then, when you return in the page, retrieve the `carouselIndex` and assign to it the `active` class.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active" data-index="0">
            <img src="img1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">First slide</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">Second slide</div>
        </div>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS (with jQuery):**

```
$(function() {
    var carouselIndex = sessionStorage.getItem("carouselIndex");
    if (!!carouselIndex) {
        $("#myCarousel").carousel(carouselIndex);
    }
    $("#myCarousel .item").click(function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("carouselIndex", $(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
});
```