# Use variable from another js file

Tags: javascript

How can I use a variable that is creats in first.js in two.js?
Notice: the two files are linked to two different html pages.

I didn't try anything cause I don't have any idea
**Notice:** I can't use the same js file because there's function that work for the first htmls file but I don't want them to work for the second one,that's why I'm using two js files

Comment: How are these two different html pages related to each other?

Comment: They are not,after completed some steps in the first html file, a button take the user to the second,but I need some variables that I took from the first page to use in the second one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing javascript variables between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581543/passing-javascript-variables-between-pages)

Comment: You can use [Sesson Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) for pertist value across multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) for persist value acros multiple pages.

You can save value using:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Name", "Hiren");
```

You can get value using:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by exporting that variable and import it into another file

for exa-
**first.js**

```
export const message = "Hello";
```

**two.js**

```
import { message } from "./utils.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't as soon as you leave first html page script reload and everything is set back to initial value.

Some workarounds are using `localStorage/sessionStorage`

Or you can create SPA(single page application) using react or vanilla js