# Duplicate field value into included file field

Tags: javascript, html

Well, as the title says, I would like to duplicate a certain field value into a field which is included by div, from another file.

I have it working without the included file. But when I cut out the second field with its form out and paste it into another file, which next off is included by `<object>` element, it won't paste it anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/amstel/9tmPC/1/

Fyi, the code isn't working in jsfiddle, is does when published, I don't know the correct setting in jsfiddle.

And, the `<object>` element I use is simply:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:200px;">
<object type="text/html" data="URL"
        style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
</object>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that it isn't in pure JS but it's very easy in jQuery.

```
$( "#yes" ).click(function() {
  duplicate();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9tmPC/8/

**Update:** Sorry I misread what you wanted. What you seem to need is to pass a variable between two pages. This can be done with:

- Cookies
- localStorage
- GET Variables

Please see: 
[how to exchange variables between two HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages)