# Pass data between partials files

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have a `form` where user enters the username/email in `login.html` partial and clicks on forgot password link. Now the user is being redirected to `forgotpwd.html`, but I am unable to access the username/email that the user entered earlier. I know this can be done using service but I am unable to do so, please do let me know how this can be done. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 storage objects such as **sessionStorage** or **localStorage**.

Please take look this - [Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/passing-data-between-html-pages)

Some other examples -
[Sharing a variable between multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264253/sharing-a-variable-between-multiple-html-pages)
[how to exchange variables between two HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages)

Comment: How does this exactly help with the question? Why don't you provide a fitting code sample?