# Bring AJAX response to new page

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using AJAX to fetch JSON data. The user fills out a form with some addresses, and these addresses are posted using AJAX. The response will either be `"status": "fail"`, `"status": "unknown"` or `"status": "success"` + a lot of other stuff based on the status. Each status should cause a new page to load with the rest of the response.

My issue is getting the data to the new page.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"https://domain.local/",
  type:"POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "json",
  data : data,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.result.Status == " fail ") {
      // head to fail.php and show response
    }

    else if (data.result.Status == " unknown ") {
      // head to unknown.php and show response
    }

    else if (data.result.Status == " success ") {
      // head to succes.php and show response
    }
   }
});
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: well on ur server side dont render back to the page according to the result resnder the page from your server side

Answer (score 1):

- Make a form in java script dynamically. With an hidden field.
- Put the data of response in a hidden field.
- Post to a page that can simple read hidden field value and display it.
- Force form data to be posted in new tab.

Comment: Wouldn't I then need to add the response to the url to be able to fetch it from the new page?

Comment: no you will put the response in string format in hidden field, use type=post for form, in this way you do not need to append in url, on server side read data from post, for instance in PHP $_POST['hidden_field_name']

Comment: It's (as far as I could figure out) not possible to do this with PHP anyway, as the form is submitted using a JS function that then redirects to a success or a fail page.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Cookies**:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

**Attach own property into Window Object**:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

```
if (data.result.Status == " fail ") {
  window.myOwnData = data;
  window.location.href = "fail.php";
}
```

**Pass your data as GET parameter of redirect url**

```
if (data.result.Status == " fail ") {
  window.location.href = "fail.php?someData=" + data + "&someOtherData=" + otherData ;
}
```

**EDIT**

Or use **JSSession**, discussion here: [Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)

I guess theres much more options

Comment: using cookies is very bad, as they will be moved through every http call

Comment: Also, I'm not allowed to use cookies for this service.

Comment: How would I go about using custom properties in the window object? I've tried just creating a string (`window.myOwnData = "test";`) and then on the new page I'm trying to append `window.MyOwnData` to a `div`, but nothing shows.

Comment: properties name missmatch, `myOwnData` and `MyOwnData`

Comment: Sorry, is miswrote. In my code, though, it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Here's the copied code: `window.Addresses = "test"; window.location.href = "bookTrip2.php";`. Then on bookTrip2.php: `$("#bookTrip").append(window.Addresses);`

Comment: I guess it's not that good solution as it might not work across browser. Try using get parameters, parse them on server side and pass data to next page

Comment: Is it possible to do this securely, and only on fail?

Comment: Would it be an option to use JSON stringify and then send it using AJAX somehow?

Comment: Found JSSession for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages

Comment: That seems pretty sweet. Thanks, I'll give it at go and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.href` to specify the page you wish to redirect

```
if (data.result.Status == " fail ") {
      window.location.href = "http://xyz.com/fail.php";
    }

    else if (data.result.Status == " unknown ") {
      window.location.href = "http://xyz.com/unknown.php";
    }

    else if (data.result.Status == " success ") {
      window.location.href = "http://xyz.com/success.php";
    }
```

Comment: I know I can use window.location, I need to figure out how to send the data from the current page to the next page.

Comment: @pshoeg For sending data, you can use COOKIE