# Regarding cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting a session cookie in one page using

```
setCookie("cookietime","1000");
```

And resetting it to "" on going back to previous page

```
setCookie("cookietime","");
```

When I go back I am showing an alert after seeting the cookie to "". it is showing "" in alert.
But in the next page it still shows "1000".
Is the cookie page specific

Comment: maybe you have to reset the given expire date too. try `-1`

Comment: when you are referring to `in the next page it still shows "1000"`, does that page set the cookie to 1000?

Comment: Please accept an answer if one of the solutions provided has helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are stored client side and are computer+browser specific not page specific! I guess you are using document.cookie which should persist through the session - they persist even when the page is refreshed. Using window.name will only persist through the same browser window but will clear on page refresh. [HTML5 localStorage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) may be a suitable alternative.

Relates question: [Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)

Answer (score 0):

`Session cookies` are temporary cookie files that will be removed when you close your browser.

`Persistent cookies` remain on your browser until it expires or until you erase them.

Neither are page specific.

Note that session cookies in `Firefox` will be restored after a browser restart when you use the session restore feature, which can cause some inconsistencies.