# How to send a value to another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i send a value from my website to another website, i have a webiste1 and another website2 they have a same form with one textbox and one button and only the website1 is the only where Im going to enter and write some code and website2 is static and i will not going to mess the code of it, and after i enter a value from website1 this will going to send the value of it into website2 and website2 will open and i will see the value that i enter.

So far i have this

website1.html

```
<input type="text" name="cat-name" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="foo()" />


function foo() {
    var cname = document.getElementsByName('cat-name')[0].value;
    //some code....
    location.href='website2.html?cat-name = cname';
    }
```

website2.html

```
<input type="text" name="cat-name" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="sendtorealserver()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)

Then you have to set the value:

```
<input type="text" name="cat-name" class="predefined"/>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="sendtorealserver()" />
```

and then

```
document.querySelector(".predefined").value = result;
```

Comment: Hello are you referring for the website2  @Vandervals the website2 or page2 is not going to be modify only the website1

Comment: If site2 is not modifiable then they must have a way yo receive that Info. You should refer to that way and that of course will be diffetent forma every other other site

Comment: Yes, there is any way that the site2 can receive that info from website1 and will display the value of it into the textbox?

Comment: Yes the site2 or website2 is not modifiable, and there is any way ? That if i click the submit button from site1 this will send the value into site2 and will display into the site2 textbox? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to edit the window2.html to read the sent params and set it to the input;
Pseudo code

```
window.onload = function(){{
  // read url params
  // set the value
  // document.getElementsByName('cat-name')[0].value = value_from_read_params
}
```

You can see how to get params from url here [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Comment: Site2 should not be modify @roxxy only site1

Comment: I don't think you can set the value in the input without modifying Site2.