# How to hold the form data from one page and show it in after two pages without session and database

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to display my first page data in third page without session or database.

here is my page1.php form.

```html
 <form  method="post" action="page1">
    name<input type="text" name="name">
    password<input type="password" name="pass">
    retype password<input type="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

it post the value to page two. and my page2.php contain one button. if i click that button means it goes to page2

```html
<form method="post" action="page3">
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$name= $_POST["name"];
$pass= $_POST["pass"];
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit">
</form>
```

now i need to display fist page data to here in page3.php

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
{
$name= $_POST["name"];
$pass= $_POST["pass"];
echo $name;
echo $pass;
}
```

please any one give idea to make this thing to work.
thank you.

Comment: You can create some hidden fields in page 2 and assign $_POST['name'] and other one to hidden fields, so that you can get it on page 3 using POST

Comment: first page is index.php

Comment: @GaganUpadhyay give much easy and correct solution you just put hidden field in page2 get that value in page3 using post method..

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have almost 30 fields, in first page in contain 10 fields and 2 page contains 20 feilds. and also i need to skip 3 pages for my project. so it is difficult to make hidden fields

Comment: @PadmaRubhan, I didn't suggest you 'hidden fields' - you have confused in suggestions

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest then give me some best solution.

Comment: @PadmaRubhan, I'll be in 30 minutes ...

Comment: @PadmaRubhan, do you intend to use a single js file for all `page1.php`, `page2.php`, `php3.php` pages?

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest, if possible, s..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can maintain the data without using session variable or database storage, using the "input type=hidden" property like this

```
  <form method="post" action="page3">
  <?php
      if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
             $name= $_POST["name"];
             $pass= $_POST["pass"];
        }
  ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<?php echo $pass; ?>"> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit">
  </form>
```

And you can retrieve this values in your 3rd form using post variables like this..

```
   <?php
          if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
           {
              $name= $_POST["name"];
              $pass= $_POST["pass"];
              echo $name;
              echo $pass;
             }
   ?>
```

Although I personally wouldn't recommend this method for a sensitive data as passwords, as the users can see the values in html form if they need to, using inspect element.

Comment: I think this answer is what you can implement.But best solution will be to store the values in session variables. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1981681/1920918