# How to send the user to a new URL?

Tags: php, html, url

This is my current [URL](http://www.onetechsearch.com/recipes/?search=&images=1&from=&to=&cat=all).

I've had this new project now for some time and I was wondering if:

1. There is a way that when the user clicks Gadgets it sends him to .... `cat=gadgets`, and it also remembers the previous selections
2. How can I transform that awful looking dropdown list into something more appealing like radio or just two basic buttons.

My code:

```
<div id="advanced-search">
    <form action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/recipes" method="GET" id="searchF1">
        <?php
        $searched_term = get_query_var('recipe_search');
        if (empty($searched_term)) {
            $searched_term = isset($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : "";
        }
        ?>
        <input id="sfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="keywords" <?php if (!empty($searched_term)) {echo 'value="'.$searched_term.'"';} ?>>
        <select id="img" name="images">
            <option value="1" <?php if($_GET["images"]=='1'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>with pictures</option>
            <option value="0" <?php if($_GET["images"]=='0'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>without pictures</option>
        </select>
        <div id="time-side">
            <!--<small>Published time</small>-->
            <input type="text" id="from-side" name="from" placeholder="Start date">
            <input type="text" id="to-side" name="to" placeholder="End date">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Tech">
        <input type="submit" value="Gadgets">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your page is vulneragle to `SQL Injection`.

Comment: You can store previous category in session

Comment: And how exactly can I store them?

Comment: to store data on the client rather than cookies you need to use sessions, take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp      and here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages/1981706#1981706

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I still don't get how can I send the user to a custom url based on what he picked cause I've tried and it didn't work. My question is what exactly do i need to change n my code in order to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can save data over multiple pages in a few different ways.

1. **url**: You can transfer data through url's, like this: `example.com/index.php?id=12345` You can then get the `id` through `$_GET`, like this `$_GET['id']`
2. **session** You can save a value in a session, probably your best option for the saving of the previous data. You can save a value like this: `$_SESSION["key"] = "value";` then you can acces that value anywhere on your website like this: `$_SESSION["key"]`. Very nice and simple.
3. **cookies** You can store a cookie just like you can with `$_SESSION` but now it's saved on the users computer as long as you want. Please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) if you want to use it.

So in your case, you can send your `catagory` information through the url. Like this: `example.com/file.php?catagory=toyota`. To get that data in your php code you can do it like this: `$_GET['catagory']`

The storing of the data of your previous section

```
$_SESSION["previoussection"] = "some value";
```

You can then later acces it like this:
    `$_SESSION["previoussection"]` and you will get `"some value"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 session_start();//starting session
$searched_term = isset($_GET["search"]) ? filter_var($_GET["search"],FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : "";
if(!empty($search_term)){

    $_SESSION = array();//emptying session for putting new data
    $_SESSION['previous'] = $search_term;//add the new search term to the session with previous key
}else{

    if(!empty($_SESSION['previous'])){//if session is not empty
        $search_term = $_SESSION['previous'];//put the old data to the search term variable
    }   
}

?>
    <div id="advanced-search">
       <form action="recipes" method="GET" id="searchF1">                
       <input id="sfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="keywords" <?php if (!empty($searched_term)) {
      echo 'value="'.$searched_term.'"';} ?>>

        <input type="radio" name="images" value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='1'){ 
                echo 'Checked';} ?>>with pictures</option>
          <input type="radio" name="images" value="0" <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='0'){ 
                echo 'checked';} ?>>without pictures</option>
        </select>
         <div id="time-side">
              <input type="text" id="from-side" name="from" placeholder="Start date">
              <input type="text" id="to-side" name="to" placeholder="End date">
          </div>
           <input type="submit" name="Tech" value="Tech">
           <input type="submit" name="cat" value="Gadgets">
          </form>
     </div>
```

You have two button Tech and Gadgets, so in order to send the way you in the url, you need name value pair:

```
       <input type="submit" name="Tech" value="Tech">
       <input type="submit" name="cat" value="Gadgets">
```

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/wp-includes/formatting.php:5011

Comment: I made the functions work, but on my sidebar it keeps showing the warning. Is there anyway I can make them dissapear?

Comment: Put session start at the beginning of your script.

Comment: It's at the beggining of the file, but the warning keeps showing. Is there a way to supress it?

Comment: Did you use session_start() in other file which you might happen to include in this file. Or you may include file which has session_start(), in that case you won't need use sesstion_start at all. You can also hide the error by putting `error_reporting(0);` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know how can I transform select into 2 radio buttons insted of the ugly list?

Comment: This is what I've done so far, but it doesn;t even display the radio buttons.                                                                    <id="img" name="images" input type="radio" value="1">
      <?php if($_GET["images"]=='1'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>with pictures
   <id="img" name="images" input type="radio" value="0" >
      <?php if($_GET["images"]=='0'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>without pictures

Comment: Try this:
<input type="radio" name="images" value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='1'){ 
     echo 'Checked';} ?>>with pictures</option>
              <input type="radio" name="images" value="0" <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='0'){ 
     echo 'checked';} ?>>without pictures</option>

Comment: Thank you so so so so so so so much, you are awesome

Comment: It is just a waste of time helping you if you don't click the tick icon.